# SQLite and time searching issues

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite table with three coloumns called day, start_time and end_time. I've added the times in the format of HH:MM and set the type to TEXT as per the SQLite recommendations for time storage. The problem comes when I try and search for times...

```
    try {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE day = :day AND start_time <= :time AND end_time >= :time');
        $stmt->execute(array('day' => $day, 'time' => $time));
        $result_arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(empty($result_arr)) {
            return 'No lessons found';
        }
        else {
            return $result_arr;
        }   
    }
```

With the above, it has no problem searching for the day only.. but when it comes to the time it has a problem. With the statement below return no results when it should have?

```
   SELECT * FROM "lesson" WHERE day = 3 AND start_time <= 10:52 AND end_time >= 10:52
```

I've played around with direct SQL statements and was only able to get the select to return any results was to encapsulate the times in single quotes.

```
    SELECT * FROM "lesson" WHERE day = 3 AND start_time <= '10:52' AND end_time >= '10:52'
```

I then tried to strval() the time but still can't get it to work. Is there a method of passing the time with the single quotes through in the statement, or am I doing something else wrong which should allow me to select without them. Maybe even a more efficient way?

I'm relatively new to databases and I've spent hours playing around with it. There's most probably an easy answer. I just don't have it... Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you know, SQLite doesn't recognize dates, and you choose `TEXT`. So, your times are strings, which must be enclosed in quotes. Did you check if your times are in `HH:MM` format? Isn't it happening to have times as `9:30` or `10:0` instead of `09:30` and `10:00`?

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual to part date and time. Use single field ("moment"):

```
CREATE TABLE lesson(
 ...
 ,moment DATETIME
);
```

DATETIME type means nothing to SQLite but is useful to the developer. Store time (+ date) in strings that follow this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Read more [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), "Time strings".

Create index on that field to speed up queries:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_lesson_moment ON lesson(moment)
```

Select records:

```
SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE moment >= '2013-10-30' AND moment < '2013-10-31'
SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE moment >= '2013-10-30 10:00' AND moment < '2013-10-30 11:00'
```

You can also use parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE moment >= ? AND moment <= ?
```

and pass time as a string value

Comment: 1: Your not answering question. 2: Caution, `DATETIME` columns [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) is `NUMERIC`! 3: It seams paramters are already being used `$stmt->execute(array('day' => $day, 'time' => $time));`.

Answer (score 0):

For your application the type TEXT is wrong. Make two columns with hour and minute with INTEGER types, then you can fire up a select.

Comment: `TEXT` is not wrong. Is a choice - a good one, from my point of view. Why would `INTEGER` be better?